# Calling Nodejs script from an html click button

Tags: html, node.js, click, client-server

I want to call a specific nodejs script from my html submit button.

I have working client-server side code, but I want to improve my html-to-client-side to call a nodejs script.

serverside.js

```
console.log('Server-side code running');

const app = express();
const port = 80;
// serve files from the public directory

app.use(express.static('public'));

// serve the homepage
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server is listening on port: %s', port);
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/htmlcode.html');
});

app.post('/clicked', (req, res) => {
    const click = {clickTime: new Date()};
    console.log(click);
    fs.open('testfile.txt', 'w', (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Saved!');
    });
});
```

htmlcode.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <button id="myButton">Submit</button>
  </body>
  <script src="toclient.js"></script>
</html>
```

toclient.js

```
console.log('Client-side code running');

const button = document.getElementById('myButton');
button.addEventListener('click', (err) => {
  console.log('button was clicked');

  fetch('/clicked', {method: 'POST'})
    .then(function(response) {
      if(response.ok) {
        console.log('Click was recorded');
        return;
      }
      throw new Error('Request failed.');
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

I would like to improve my nodejs-calling html button to something similar to onClick. (Basically on clicking the submit button, execute the toclient.js)

Comment: Can you provide more details on how you'd like to improve it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are just using plain javascript on the front end. You should look into using a framework  like angular or angularjs